# The meaning of ${\infty}^{k}$.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

When we say, that, say, a surface contains ${\infty}^{k}$ lines, do we mean that it contains a k-parameter family of lines? Do we assume that this family is parametrized by a $P^{k}$, say, or we use this term more informally?
This is certainly a standard notation, but I didn't see its explanation in standard modern textbooks.

Comment: I have never seen the notation $\infty^k$ in algebraic geometry.  Could you provide a reference?  

Comment: @Pete: Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths and Harris, page 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology is fairly common in classical works on projective algebraic/differential geometry. I am not aware of its origins. Anyway it is used rather informally and only means
that you have a $k$-dimensional "continuous" family of objects. The parameter space usually is only local and should be thought as a small ball in $\mathbb C^k$.